# Replacing empty integer cells with 0 in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view

```
matches_view
```

returning the following:

```
 id |      name      | wins | losses | matches
----+----------------+------+--------+---------
  2 | Peter          |    1 |      2 |       3
  1 | Kevin          |    3 |      1 |       4
  3 | John           |      |      1 |
```

How can I replace the empty columns in the last row with 0s in postgreSQL?

Comment: What is the view definition? I'm guessing the "empty" fields are `null`, so it might be as easy as using `COALESCE(field, 0)`, but it's impossible to tell withough knowing how the view is generated.

Comment: Very good, that did the job! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE(<expression>, 0)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) for numeric columns in *any case*.